# Is ELM327 able to auto-connect to my android phone? How to know if it's already connecting on my phone without open OBD2 app?

Tags: android, bluetooth, obd-ii, elm327

I use ELM327 OBD2 Bluetooth. My use case is auto-connecting my Android phone to OBD2 via Bluetooth. But it seems OBD2 Bluetooth can't auto connect to my device. It does have pairing, but I didn't know is it really connected to my phone or not. I use Xiaomi Redmi Note 3G.

My question: Is ELM327 able to auto-connect to my android phone? How to know if it's already connecting on my phone without open OBD2 app?

Answer (score 0):

ELM327 will not auto-connect to your phone. It needs to be told to do so by issuing a valid PID (e.g. `0100`) after specifying which protocol to use (e.g. with `ATSP0`).

If the connection has been successful you will receive a valid answer. If not, you'll get a `BUS INIT ERRROR` (or the like).